# while webcrawling, computer doesn't stack the title what I wanted to crawl

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to crawl title of this webpage, but title's result is always [].
what did I did wrong? and what is the proper html CSS selector if title?

---

```
import urllib.request as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("./title_crawl.txt", "w")
page_num = 1
while True:
    url = "https://gall.dcinside.com/mgallery/board/lists/?id=of&page={}".format(page_num)
    code = req.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(code, "html.parser")
    title = soup.select("td>a")
    for i in range(len(title)):
        print(title[i].text)
        f.write(title[i].text)
        if len(title) == 0:
           break
        page_num += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The website is rendered dynamically, so you might want to try the selenium library for that.

1. Install the libraries:

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver-manager
```

2. Get the webpage html:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Use the browser in a headless mode
options = Options()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

page_num = 1
url = "https://gall.dcinside.com/mgallery/board/lists/?id=of&page={}".format(page_num)

page = driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
```

3. Parse it with BeautifulSoup

```
# parse the page with Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

4. Print out the titles :

```
# Get the title
title = soup.select("td>a")

for i in range(len(title)):
    print(title[i].text)
```

Hope these are what you wanted in the first place. Good luck!
[image: scraped titles]